# Flask App with Slow Queries, Multiple Client Users, and Hosted on Kubernetes

Tags: python, flask, kubernetes

I've got a Flask app in which I hope to accomplish the following things:

1. Have an endpoint that will run a series of queries
2. This endpoint needs to respond to the HTTP request within a limited number of seconds.
3. The queries can take up to several minutes to finish so I need them to run in a separate thread, with multiple clients polling the server every so often to see if they have fresh data to be returned to them
4. Hopefully hosted on Kubernetes with multiple instances of the pod running.

My below implementation has several issues:

1. The poll endpoint seems unnecesarily large, most of this is just dealing with the Queue of queries and making sure that each client gets their own results back, and not someone elses.
2. Not sure what is going on, but when I try to host more than one instance of this pod on Kubernetes, its like some poll requests from some users are being sent to instances in which their uuid does not exist.

I'm hoping for some understanding of what I'm doing wrong with threading and Queues because this seems like a hacky way of doing this. And also, how can I make the results of these queries available to all instances of Kubernetes running?

Thanks!

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify, g
from Queue import Queue
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep


app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='Templates')


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.before_first_request
def before_first_request():
    g.output = Queue()
    g.data_results = {}
    return ""


@app.route('/data')
def data():
    """
    Endpoint hit to fire of a request for data from a given user (uuid)
    """
    params = request.args.to_dict()
    uuid = params['uuid']
    # Create a list for this user, to store their results
    g.data_results[uuid] = [] 
    list_of_queries = ["SELECT * FROM tbl1;", 
                       "SELECT * FROM tbl2;", 
                       "SELECT * FROM tbl3;"]
    for query in list_of_queries:
         t = Thread(target=worker, args=(query, uuid, g.output))
         t.daemon = True
         t.start()
    return jsonify({'msg':'Queries started'})


def worker(*args):
    query, uuid, output = args
    # Will actually be something like `result = run_query(query)`
    result = {'uuid':uuid}
    sleep(10)
    output.put(result)


@app.route('/poll')
def poll():
    """
    Endpoint hit ever x seconds from frontend
    to see if the data is ready
    """
    params = request.args.to_dict()
    uuid_from_client = params['uuid']
    # If client polls for result, but server has no record of this uuid
    # This can happen in kubernetes with multiple instances running
    if g.data_results.get(uuid_from_client) is None:
        return jsonify({'msg':'pong', 'data':None, 'freshdata':None})
    try:
        output = g.output
        # This line throws an error if there is nothing to get
        results = output.get(False)
        output.task_done()
        # What is the uuid associated with the most recently returned data
        # More than 1 chunk of data can be in here
        uuid_from_data = results['uuid']
        g.data_results[uuid_from_data].append(results)
    except:
        uuid_from_data = None
        results = None

    results_for_client_uuid = g.data_results[uuid_from_client]
    if len(results_for_client_uuid) > 0:
        res = results_for_client_uuid.pop(0)
    else:
        res = None
    return jsonify({'msg':'pong', 'data':res})


if __name__ == "__main__":
    with app.app_context():
        app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

Comment: you should look into Celery for this.

Answer (score 0):

Setup your app architecture to use queuing softwares so that there is separation of concerns in terms of what job it does.

Here is a great article that can help you give some insight http://blog.gorgias.io/deploying-flask-celery-with-docker-and-kubernetes/
and one more https://endocode.com/blog/2015/03/24/using-googles-kubernetes-to-build-a-distributed-task-management-cluster/